# How to make Highchart 2 or more inner Pie but only 1 outer pie with donut type?

Tags: highcharts, donut-chart

I need a chart with 2 or more inner Pie Slice and 1 outer pie with donut type of Highchart plugin.

Here is the donut example :

http://tinyurl.com/d4fp8p9

Here is jsfiddle. It has categories and each category has more than 1 data. What I want ? I have categories but each category doesn't have data. There is only 1 slice that have data for outer pie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NTkSc/)

Actually you need to remove `drilldown` attribute from the pie that has no link with donut pie and check the data with:

```
 if(data[i].drilldown!=undefined){
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].drilldown.data.length; j++) {
        var brightness = 0.2 - (j /data[i].drilldown.data.length) / 5 ;
        versionsData.push({
            name: data[i].drilldown.categories[j],
            y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
            color: Highcharts.Color(data[i].color).brighten(brightness).get()
        });
    }
}}
```

or put empty drilldown like [this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NTkSc/1/)

Comment: thanks. First, I tried to remove drilldown attribute. But I didnt achieve. I solved the problem with putted empty drilldown.

Comment: I can't, because my reputation down to 15... :) accept my question first then accept to your answer :)